# WCF BasicHttpBinding Http Post

Tags: wcf, http-post, basichttpbinding

Is it possible to post to a WCF service hosted in IIS? I know that that this is possible using REST but I really need the WSDL generation and SOAP headers. I need to transition an existing ASMX web services to WCF but I need to also allow my clients to continue to utilize the service via http posts (xml http request via javascript). Is REST my only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, with a SOAP service, you need to use the SOAP methods and actions - you cannot use HTTP POST to "dump" some data on a SOAP service.

If you need HTTP POST, then REST is the way to go.

Comment: I was afraid of that. So the only way to consume a WCF web service is to add a service reference to the client?

Comment: @Quadwwchs: if it's a SOAP-style web service - yes, you need to add a Service Reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use REST style WCF 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx

Comment: Thanks! REST looks great with the exception of no WSDL.